# is it possible to 100% auto-generate swagger documentation in expressjs

Tags: express, swagger, swagger-ui

Is it possible to auto-generate a swagger documentation for an Expressjs API without having to add comments To routes ? I am using swagger-jsdoc and swagger-ui-expres

I tried swagger-autogen , but it requires adding details to routes.